# Is there any api which can convert spring batch job object to xml-based job?

Tags: spring-batch

I programmatically got a Job object(instance of SimpleJob class).Then for some reason, I wanna convert this job object to job1.xml(xml-based job definition file). So that I can save the job on my hard disk. Is there any spring batch java api which can achieve this? Something like:

SimpleJob job1 = new SimpleJob("SomeJob");

job1.addSomeStep()... //create the details of the job

SomeConverter(job1, "job1.xml");//then we got the job1.xml on the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

No Idea why you want to do it that way,there should be some solid reason.

There is an Marshler and Unmarshler available in Spring-Oxm.

Spring oxm is - Spring Object XML Mappers 
This module help in the mapping between java objects and XML documents

There is no need to write code over here ,

This is what you can refer exactly -

```
https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-objectxml-mapping-example/
```

in the given answer @ above link - you can use your SumpleJob object instead of customer - use the SimpleJob as shown below

```
   <batch:job id="SimpleJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            ......
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

You also need to create a class for SimpleJob - which will be used in mapping

```
<mapping>
    <class name="com.test.SampleJob">

        <map-to xml="sampleJob" />

   <!-- and below here you need to mention all the , mapping using fields -->

        <field name=".." type="..">
            <bind-xml name=".." node=".." />
        </field>

    </class>
</mapping>
```

And because it is Mr.mkyoung - the code written on his site will always work :)

Comment: @Geralt.J .. did u go throguh my answer , was it help full ..?